# Disable choices in multiselect Django widget

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Is it possible to disable a few select choices in a Django multiselect widget?

I can do something like this in the view:

```
        id_roles = (10, 2, 1, 3, 11)
        self.fields['role'].queryset = Role.objects.filter(id__in=id_roles)
```

But this would throw an error when saving bound forms with values outside that list. Can I have all the roles there, just disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to setup your own custom Widget to achieve such behavior.

```py
from django import forms

class MyWidget(forms.SelectMultiple):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.active_choices = kwargs.pop('active_choices', [])
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def create_option(self, name, value, *args, **kwargs):
        option = super().create_option(name, value, *args, **kwargs)
        option['attrs']['disabled'] = value not in self.active_choices
        return option


class MyForm(forms.Form):

    role = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Role.objects.all(), widget=MyWidget())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        active_choices = kwargs.pop('active_choices', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if active_choices:
            self.fields['role'].widget.active_choices = active_choices
```

Comment: I want them to be there but disabled, not to exclude them.

Comment: Then you'll have to create your own field and your own widget. This is not built in Django out of the box.